# Java Generic Method - Cannot instantiate Class with generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

Following example is not the original code, I'm not looking for a workaround.

There is a Class For Generic Parsing/UnMarshalling like:

```
public class UnMarshaller<T extends AClass> {
...
```

This works fine, until I try to provide a Generic Method to access it.

```
public class UnMarshall{
...
// the T schema is every time a Subclass of AClass
public <T extends AClass> Queue<T> instantiateSomething(Input i, T schema) {
    UnMarshaller<schema> unmarshaller= new UnMarshaller<schema>(schema, i);
    return unmarshaller.getQueue();
}
...
```

UnMarshaller<**schema**> and  new UnMarshaller<**schema**> are troubleing, but i doesn't get it. How can I instantiate this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a generic type parameter, supply the class/type name, not the variable name:

```
UnMarshaller<T> unmarshaller = new UnMarshaller<T>(schema, i);
```

Comment: Its working. So the schema is useless? I'm able to do the method call like <SubClasOfA>instantiateSomething(new Input()); ?

Comment: It doesn't look like `schema` is useless, depending on its purpose.  You pass it to the `UnMarshaller` constructor.  If the only purpose of it is to define `T`, then it's not necessary.